# Django login always return anonymous user

Tags: python, django, session, authentication, django-forms

I wrote a simple login function as below. The Django development version is 1.9.8 and python version is 3.5.

`The login function`

```
def login(req):
    if req.method == "POST":
        username = req.POST.get("username")
        password = req.POST.get("psw")
        kwargs = {'username': username, 'password': password}
        user_ = auth.authenticate(**kwargs)

        if user_ is not None and user_.is_active:
            auth.login(req,user_)
            return render(req, "home.html", {"status": "Logged In Successess"})
        else:
            return render(req, "home.html", {"status": "Log In Failed. Check!"})

    else:
        return render(req, "login.html")

else:
    return render(req, "login.html")
```

`settings.py`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=[
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "shop.customer"
```

After inserting lots of breakpoints to observe the authentication behavior, I found that the error occurs in the instruction(line 18~19) in the Django source `https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/contrib/auth/backends.py`.

```
    if user.check_password(password):
        return user
```

It always returns me an `anonymous user`. So I turn to create a superuser
and try it again. The same result continues. Somebody please give me hints and suggestions, thank you!!!

Update:

This is my `shop.customer` model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
BaseUserManager, AbstractUser
)
class customer(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

Comment: Do you have a custom user model or auth backend? How did you create the users in the first place?

Comment: post your `shop.customer` model

Comment: I only inherit the `auth.models.AbstractUser` .